# Evaluate the following series involving two square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{119}\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+\frac{1}{4}}}}$$

I first decided to do some simplifications. I rewrote $n^4+\frac14$ as $\left(n^2+n+\frac12\right)\left(n^2-n+\frac12\right)$ But I cannot get things out of the square root. Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a simple whole number

Comment: Rationalize the denominator. Then study [the section on two nested square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical). You should end with a difference between square roots that telescopes when you sum the terms.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I ended up with $$\sqrt{2+4n^2-\sqrt{16n^4+4}}$$ what to do now

Comment: $$
\sqrt {2 + 4n^2  - \sqrt {16n^4  + 4} }  = \sqrt {n^2  + (n + 1)^2 }  - \sqrt {(n - 1)^2  + n^2 } 
$$ using the very last equation of this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Two_nested_square_roots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that sum is an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211245/prove-that-sum-is-an-integer) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B119%7D%5Csqrt%7B2-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%2B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E4%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D%7D%7D%7D%24)

Comment: @Gary I saw the last section and also the technique...but I'm not able to fully understand it...pls can you tell me how you did this with steps?

Comment: @MartinR let me see

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Well, it says $$
\sqrt {a - \sqrt c }  = \sqrt {\frac{{a + \sqrt {a^2  - c} }}{2}}  - \sqrt {\frac{{a - \sqrt {a^2  - c} }}{2}} ,
$$ so...